# Ada Remote_Types error "illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface"

Tags: ada

I'm developing a DBMS (database management software) completely in Ada and DSA.
But I've encountered some problem; rows are implemented as documents (MongoDB-style), and they're a protected interface, then implemented in the same package as a protected type.
I had to make it an interface first so it would be possible to have a remote access type for it (protected types canNOT have remote access types, for they are not tagged).
I'm getting the same messages for all functions being overrode (but not procedures):

```
safira-documents.ads:845:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:845:27: first formal of "Is_Version_Controlled" declared at line 737 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:856:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:856:27: first formal of "Get_Contents" declared at line 753 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:861:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:861:27: first formal of "Get_Version" declared at line 760 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:880:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:880:27: first formal of "Has_Key" declared at line 785 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:888:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:888:27: first formal of "Get_Value" declared at line 795 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:900:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:900:27: first formal of "Get_Id" declared at line 810 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:902:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:902:27: first formal of "Get_Location" declared at line 812 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:904:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:904:27: first formal of "Database" declared at line 816 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:906:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:906:27: first formal of "Collection" declared at line 820 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:908:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:908:27: first formal of "Get_Creation_Time_As_Dictionary" declared at line 824 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
safira-documents.ads:911:27: illegal overriding of subprogram inherited from interface
safira-documents.ads:911:27: first formal of "Get_Last_Update_Time_As_Dictionary" declared at line 828 must be of mode "in" or access-to-constant
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

The relevant code is this:

```
package Safira.Documents with Remote_Types, Spark_Mode => On, Elaborate_Body is
   
   type Update_Value_Operation is 
     access procedure 
       (K : in     Key;
        V : in out Value);
   
   type Base_Document is protected interface;
   -- Documents live in Storage_Nodes only. Clients access them through remote
   -- access types.
   -- This allows them to be declared as protected types with trustworthy atomic
   --  operations that won't corrupt their content.
   
   type Base_Document_Xs is access all Base_Document'Class;
   
   -- << Many subprograms for the interface here >>
   
   protected type Document is new Base_Document with
      
      overriding function Is_Version_Controlled return Boolean;
   
      overriding procedure Set_Mirror 
        (N : in     Nodename_String.Bounded_String);
   
      overriding procedure Remove_From_Mirror 
        (N : in     Nodename_String.Bounded_String);
   
      overriding procedure Set_Contents 
        (D : in     Dictionary'Class);
   
      overriding function Get_Contents return Dictionary'Class;
   
      overriding procedure Revert_To 
        (Version : in     Document_Version);
   
      overriding function Get_Version 
        (Version : in     Document_Version)
         return Dictionary'Class;
   
      overriding procedure Delete_Version 
        (Version : in     Document_Version);
   
      overriding procedure Define_New_Origin 
        (From : in     Document_Version);
   
      overriding procedure Delete_Entire_History;
   
      overriding procedure Clone_From 
        (Origin  : access Document);
   
      overriding procedure Clone_From 
        (Origin  : access Document;
         Version : in     Document_Version);
   
      overriding function Has_Key 
        (K : in     Key) 
         return Boolean;
   
      overriding procedure Set_Value 
        (K : in     Key;
         V : in     Value'Class);
   
      overriding function Get_Value 
        (K : in     Key) 
         return Value'Class;
   
      overriding procedure Update_Value 
        (K : in     Key;
         V : in     Value'Class);
   
      overriding procedure Update_Value 
        (K  : in     Key;
         Op : in     Update_Value_Operation);
   
      overriding function Get_Id return Document_Id;
   
      overriding function Get_Location return Nodename_String.Bounded_String;
   
      overriding function Database return Blueprint_String.Bounded_String;
   
      overriding function Collection return Blueprint_String.Bounded_String;
   
      overriding function Get_Creation_Time_As_Dictionary 
        return Dictionary'Class;
   
      overriding function Get_Last_Update_Time_As_Dictionary 
        return Dictionary'Class;
      
   private
      
      Contents : Dictionary;
      
   end Document;

end Safira.Documents;
```

Turning those `access` parameters into `in` ones in the interface's spec (apparently) fixes the problem. But I don't know if this will break the remote functionality. All Remote_Types examples I could find in the internet used access parameters for remote types' methods.

Apparently, the interface's functions expect an access to constant argument (i.e. *actual parameter*), I didn't ask for it, so I'm sure this is some Ada default security/safety feature.

Now... Can I just change the `access` parameters to `in` ones without breaking the remote functionality? If not, is there any way to avoid this default behavior (in other words, make them access to variable parameters)?
All examples I found for Remote_Types used `access` parameters, so I'm afraid my solution of turning them into `in` parameters could make them normal (non-remote) methods, which would render this package useless as a Remote_Types in a distributed application. I could try to make it Pure, but don't know if that could be done easily.

P.S.: It's supposed to be open-sourced in the future (when it's ready), so if I really need to, I can publish the whole file or the whole project now.
I don't like to publish my projects before they're ready, but if it's necessary in order for someone to find a solution for this... I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide profiles of protected functions, but it looks like you miss `constant` keyword for access parameters:

```
type PI is protected interface;
function Is_Version (Self : access constant PI) return Boolean
   is abstract;

protected type D is new PI with
     overriding function Is_Version return Boolean;
private
   Ok : Boolean;
end D;
```

Regarding to `in` vs `access` for remote types, there should be no
difference for interface/protected types, because in Ada they are passed by references anyway.